# Developing in power series

Tags: power-series

I would like to develop in power series $\frac{1}{(2+x)^3}$ and
 $ \frac{1}{(32-x)^{1/5}} $. What is the way to go ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite as $$\frac18\cdot\frac1{\Bigl(1-\dfrac x2\Bigr)^3}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac12\cdot\frac1{\Bigl(1-\dfrac x{32}\Bigr)^{1/5}},$$
and use the binomial formula.